# How can I output all objects in a vector using for loop in c++

Tags: c++, object, vector

A class `BookLibrary` constructs a vector of objects of class `BookInfo`. The task is to add some 'books' (objects of class `BookInfo`) into the vector and print them out. For some reason, a conventional `for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) cout << vector[i] << endl;` loop is not working. This is a homework project from Savitch textbook "Problem Solving with C++".

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class BookInfo
{
public:
    BookInfo(string newAuthor, string newTitle);
    BookInfo(string newTitle);
    string getName();
    string getAuthor();
    string getTitle();
private:
    string author;
    string title;
};

class BookLibrary
{
public:
    BookLibrary();
    BookLibrary(vector<BookInfo> newLibrary);
    void add(BookInfo newBook);
    void size();
    void printInfo();
private:
    vector<BookInfo> library;
};

int main()
{
    BookLibrary library1;
    BookInfo book1("Michael Krichton", "Jurassic Park");
    BookInfo book2("War and Peace"), book3("Valter Savitch", "Programming in C++");
    library1.add(book1);
    library1.add(book2);
    library1.add(book3);
    library1.size();
    library1.printInfo();
    return 0;
}

BookInfo::BookInfo(string newAuthor, string newTitle)
{
    author = newAuthor;
    title = newTitle;
}

BookInfo::BookInfo(string newTitle) :
    title(newTitle), author("unknown")
{}

string BookInfo::getName()
{
    return (author + " " + title);
}

string BookInfo::getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}

string BookInfo::getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

BookLibrary::BookLibrary()
{}

BookLibrary::BookLibrary(vector<BookInfo> newLibrary)
{
    library = newLibrary;
}

void BookLibrary::add(BookInfo newBook)
{
    library.push_back(newBook);
}

void BookLibrary::size()
{
    cout << library.size();
}

void BookLibrary::printInfo()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < library.size(); i++)
        cout << library[i] << endl;
}
```

It underlines the `cout <<` in the last line.

Comment: You need to provide `operator<<` for `BookInfo`.

Comment: "is not working" is not a useful problem description. This is like explaining your car problem to a mechanic by saying that "my car is not moving".

Comment: compiler 'complains': "error C2679: binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type '_Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

Comment: @kanulilewa As cigien said, you need to define an `operator<<` for `BookInfo`

Comment: I'm not sure I am familiar with this yet, how do I define it?

Comment: @kanulilewa see the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is not able to print out a `BookInfo` object, because you have not defined an `operator<<` for `BookInfo`.  As such, a statement like `cout << library[i]` does not know what to do with the `BookInfo` that `library[i]` returns.

You need to add that operator, eg:

```cpp
class BookInfo
{
public:
    ...

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const BookInfo &book)
    {
        os << "\"" << book.title << "\" by " << book.author;
        return os;
    }

    ...
};
```

If you want to use your `getName()` method instead, you would need to declare it as `const` (which you should do anyway for all of your getters), eg:

```cpp
class BookInfo
{
public:
    ...
    string getName() const;
    ...

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const BookInfo &book)
    {
        os << book.getName();
        return os;
    }

    ...
};

string BookInfo::getName() const
{
    return ...;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's new to me I'll try and add this to my code

Comment: That worked perfectly!!! Here's the updated code: class BookInfo
{
public:
    BookInfo(string newAuthor, string newTitle);
    BookInfo(string newTitle);
    string getName() const;
    string getAuthor();
    string getTitle();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const BookInfo& newBook)
    {
        os << newBook.getName();
        return os;
    }
private:
    string author;
    string title;
};

Comment: Is this subject called ostream? I'd like to do more research into this matter since it has been new to me